# PostGIS extension undefined symbol: GEOSCoordSeq_getXY

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-12, postgis-installation

I am trying to create postgis 3.0 extension on postgresql12 on centos7 (both are installed using yum native rpms)

```
yum install postgis30_12.x86_64
```

but i am getting different errors with GEOS. currently the error i am getting is

```
postgres=# create extension postgis;
```

> ERROR:  could not load library
>   "/usr/pgsql-12/lib/postgis-3.so": /usr/pgsql-12/lib/postgis-3.so:
>   undefined symbol: GEOSCoordSeq_getXY
>
> geos-config --version
>   3.8.0

Comment: can you add also the command you used to install the extension in CentOS?

Comment: yum install postgis30_12.x86_64

Comment: you probably have an older version of `geos` or multiple versions installed. Can you make sure you have only the newest one installed?

Comment: i have removed all geos installations and installed only the latest 3.8 then tried to install postgis but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PostGIS binary you are using was built with a GEOS version that is incompatible with the one installed. You have to either install a different GEOS library or a different PostGIS.

Normally, such an incompatibility should be made obvious by using a different library version. GEOS seems to be sloppy here.

Comment: I have installed geos 3.8 as per postgis documentation that postgis 3.0 is best served with geos 3.8. The problem now i don't know which geos version postgis30_12.x86_64 has been built with.

Comment: The documentation probably talks about installing from source code. You may have to experiment to find the proper version. Often it is a good idea to get both installation packages from the same source.

Comment: I have removed all geos from the machine and tried to install postgis from yum the same way in order to get geos as a dependency from yum and not to install it separately and it asked me to install geos38 and eventually getting the same error. I tried with geos 3.5, 3.7, and 3.6 also no luck. i am blocked now.

Comment: Did you use the PGDG packages for everything?

Comment: Yes. for some reason libgeos_c.so was not overwritten/used after a new geos installation

Comment: I am happy to see you have found it.

Comment: Thanks. your answer guided me to look at the right direction

Answer (score 1):

i have resolved the issue by running ldd libgeos_c.so.1 to find which one is being used by postgresql12 and manually replaced it with the one that comes after installing geos38 and the create extension succeeded.